# How to use a single Log4Net instance in mutliple Nunit TestFixtures with SetUpFixture

Tags: events, nunit, log4net

I'm just getting into the use of Selenium Webdriver and its EventFiring so that I can log any exceptions thrown by the driver to a file or email etc.

I have got Log4Net working and my Unit Tests are running fine with Selenium.

What I am having issues with is having Log4Net create 1 log file, but for multiple test fixtures.

Here are some important classes which I think I need to show you in order to explain my issue.

```
public class EventLogger : EventFiringWebDriver
{
    // Not sure if this is the best place to declare Log4Net

    public static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(EventLogger));

    public EventLogger(IWebDriver parentDriver) : base(parentDriver)
    {
        // To get Log4Net to read the configuration file on what logger to use
        // To console , file, email etc

        XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        if (Log.IsInfoEnabled)
        {
            Log.Info("Logger started.");
        }

    }

    protected override void OnFindingElement(FindElementEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnFindingElement(e);

        //TODO:

        if (Log.IsInfoEnabled)
        {
            Log.InfoFormat("OnFindingElement: {0}", e);
        }
    }       

    protected override void OnElementClicked(WebElementEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementClicked(e);

        //TODO:

        if (Log.IsInfoEnabled)
        {
            Log.InfoFormat("OnElementClicked: {0}", e.Element.GetAttribute("id"));
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my SetupFixture - which I THINK is run every time a new TestFixture class is run.

```
    [SetUpFixture]
public class BaseTest
{
    protected static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

    private FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile;
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private EventLogger eventLogger;   

    public IWebDriver StartDriver()
    {
        Common.WebBrowser = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["WebBrowser"];
        Log.Info("Browser: " + Common.WebBrowser);       

        switch (Common.WebBrowser)
        {
            case "firefox":
                {
                    firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile { AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true };
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
                    break;
                }
            case "iexplorer":
                {
                    driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                    break;
                }
            case "chrome":
                {
                    driver = new ChromeDriver();
                    break;
                }
        }

        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(Common.DefaultTimeSpan);


        // Here is where I start my EventLogger to handle the events from selenium
        // web driver, onClick, OnFindingElement etc.
        // Is this the best way? Seems a bit messy, lack of structure

        return eventLogger = new EventLogger(driver);


    }

    public EventLogger EventLogger
    {
        get { return eventLogger; }
    }

}
```

Here is one of the many TestFixtures I have, each one based on a Selenium2 PageObjects

```
[TestFixture]
public class LoginPageTest : BaseTest
{
    private IWebDriver driver;
    private LoginPage loginPage;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {         

        // Where I use the Log from the BaseTest 
        // protected static readonly ILog Log <-- top of BaseTest

        Log.Info("SetUp");


        driver = StartDriver();
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        loginPage = new LoginPage();
        PageFactory.InitElements(driver, loginPage);         
    }

    [Test]
    public void SubmitFormInvalidCredentials()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SubmitFormInvalidCredentials");


        loginPage.UserName.SendKeys("invalid");
        loginPage.Password.SendKeys("invalid");
        loginPage.SubmitButton.Click();            

        IWebElement invalidCredentials = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_insideForm_insideForm_ctl02_title"));
        Assert.AreEqual("Invalid user name or password", invalidCredentials.Text);
    }
}
```

My `Log.txt` file is obviously being re-written over and over after each `TestFixture` is run,

How can I set up my NUnit Testing so that I only run the Log4Net once, so that I can use it in both my `EventLogger` and `TestFixtures`?

I have Googled around a lot, maybe its something simple. Do I have some design issues with the structure of my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out setting explicitly `AppendToFile="True"` in the log4net configuration for the FileAppender you are using:

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="..." type="log4net.Appender....">
      <appendToFile value="true" />
```

[FileAppender.AppendToFile](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.FileAppender.AppendToFile.html) property

> Gets or sets a flag that indicates whether the file should be appended
>   to or overwritten

Regarding `[SetupFixture]`, I believe you are using it in wrong way. It not supposed to mark base class of the each TesFixture by this attribute, this looks messy. You should declare class which considered to be SetupFixture and mark it by `[SetupFixture]` attribute so it will be called ONCE for all TestFixtures within a given (declaration) namespace.

From NUnit documentation, [SetUpFixtureAttribute](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=setupFixture&r=2.4):

> This is the attribute that marks a class that contains the one-time
>   setup or teardown methods for all the test fixtures under a given
>   namespace. The class may contain at most one method marked with the
>   SetUpAttribute and one method marked with the TearDownAttribute

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I have changed the SetUpFixture like you mentioned. I still use two ILog but it's ok, they both append to the same file. 

Now each derived class can use the ILog from the base class, as I didn't declare it static anymore, so that the Logger can tell which class it's coming from, before It was always logging as BaseTest. Now It logs as LoginPageTest, SearchPageTest etc etc.

Comment: But what about `AppendToFile="true"`, is it helped you?

Comment: Yes that's what I set in the App.config in the <log4net> section. :)