# Log4Net not working in Selenium Framework when Running SpecFlow Tests

Tags: c#, selenium, logging, log4net

I'm struggling with Log4Net for a good while now. I have followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069174/how-to-use-a-single-log4net-instance-in-mutliple-nunit-testfixtures-with-setupfi) 
as an example. The difference is, in my case, I have two separate projects, one with all objects that interacts with WebDriver and web elements (`FrameworkProject`), second is actual test project(TestProject). I have read a lot and I'm almost sure I have set it correctly...
FrameworkProject assembly file includes `[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true)]`

My `Log4Net.config` file is as follow:

```
    <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>

  <log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="MyAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="MyFileAppender" />
    </root>
    <appender name="MyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="MyFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
      <file value="application.log" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

</configuration>
```

When I debug my SpecFlow tests and I reach the line `XmlConfigurator.Configure();` (look example above) I'm still getting

```
log4net:ERROR Failed to find configuration section 'log4net' in the application's.
```

This drops me mad now and I have no clue of what might be wrong. Could this be the cause of running test?? Note: I have `log4net` set up ONLY in `FrameworkProject`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have log4net set up ONLY in FrameworkProject

That's the problem. Roughly speaking, your "entry point" during test execution is your *Test Project*, hence it's looking for `log4net` configuration section inside of "entry point's" application configuration file (Test Project's `app.config`). Thus you should move your `log4net` configuration to Test Project's application configuration file.

---

On a second notice, it looks like you don't need to call `XmlConfigurator.Configure` if you use assembly level attribute: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17469229/2974754), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16776164/2974754).

Comment: Ok, I have no idea why I just didn't tried to do it way earlier...Anyway, I did as you proposed. I have copied log4net section to my App.config file. Added an configuration to assembly. Now, when I run it nothing happens...

Comment: The [assembly:...] statement is needed in the entry-point project

Comment: Got this working. Had to do bit more googling... also, I didn't noticed the application.log file being actually created in lib\debug folder... I mark this as solution as it pointed me to right direction. Thanks!